# Change default application for opening files in Firefox

Tags: 16.04, firefox

[image: how can i reset this setting]

How can I reset this setting for opening file to default or to unspecified?

This problem affects both firefox and firefox-trunc installed in Ubuntu.

UPDATE: append screenshots 
1) Can't choose other Helpers apps but shown on
2) in Mozilla->Prefs->Applications i'dont see any app for *bin* but the default program for openning is libreoffice
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you select "ask" from the dropdown and then check the "do this automagically" box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option One - Via Firefox**

In Firefox -> Preferences -> General -> Applications:

You can set "bin" to be "always ask"

[image: Firefox Preferences]

**Option Two - Nuke Your MimeTypes File**

This will reset all of your file associations.

```
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/(unique id).default/mimeTypes.rdf
```

You will need to replace (unique id) with whatever yours is named.

**Option Three - Edit Your MimeTypes File**

```
nano ~/.mozilla/firefox/(unique id).default/mimeTypes.rdf
```

Look for the part about "bin" and you can change it to something like this:

```
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:scheme:bin"
                   NC:alwaysAsk="true">
    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:scheme:handler:bin"/>
  </RDF:Description>
```

Notice the "alwaysAsk=true" part... this is what will need to be changed in your file

Comment: as advised by [kb.mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) i deleted `rm -rf  mimeTypes.rdf ` and then choose new app handler for archives as archive manager. and from now i 'm having "archive manager" just like libreoffice it cover all unknown types as default down-loader. In short words problem persist the Firefox does not ask for unknown types, but substitute a selected